# What could cause the If loop to not trigger the video pause / play function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fork a tutorial file and create an MCQ style video which has buttons that are overlayed on the video and are triggered at particular durations of the video itself.

I've got it to work mostly, except, it stopped working after the 30 sec mark of the video, I must have screwed something up, but I can't figure out what.

Ideally, at 30 sec mark, the user is given two choices.

Choice 1 resumes the play for another few seconds and pauses, indicating the end of the video.

Choice 2 skips the video for the duration of the choice 1 answer and THEN plays for a few seconds and reaches the end of the video.

But I broke this check post at 30 sec please help me fix it.

Here is my JS code is :

```
// Various variables
var videoHalfWay = 0;
var formattedHalfWay = 0;

// Choice parts
var choiceHeart = 2;
var ending = 20;              
var goodChoiceChosen = false;
var choiceHeartchosen = false;
var qualityChosen = false;
var costChosen = false;
var qualityQuestion = 30;
var costPart = 38;
var costCons = 36;

// Question variable
var question1Asked = false;

var video1;

$(document).ready(function(){

    video1 = $('#video1');

    $('.box1').on('click', function(){
        choiceHeartchosen = true;
        video1[0].play();
    });

    $('.box2').on('click', function(){

        video1[0].play();
    });

    $('.box3').on('click', function(){ //quality
        costChosen = true;
        video1[0].currentTime = costPart;
    });

    $('.box4').on('click', function(){ //cost
        qualityChosen = true;
        video1[0].play();

    });



    $(video1).on('loadeddata', function(){
        videoHalfWay = Math.round(this.duration/2);
    })


    $(video1).on('timeupdate', function()
    {
        var currentTime = Math.round(this.currentTime);
        var durationNum = Math.round(this.duration);
        var formattedCurrentTime = secondsToHms(currentTime);
        var formattedDurationTime = secondsToHms(durationNum)
        onTrackedVideoFram(formattedCurrentTime, formattedDurationTime)

        if(currentTime >2){ $(".box1, .box2").hide(); }

        if(currentTime <20){ $(".box4").hide(); }

        if(currentTime <22){ $(".box3").hide(); }

        if(currentTime >20){ $(".box4").show(); }

        if(currentTime >21){ $(".box3").show(); }

        if(currentTime >30){ $(".box3, .box4").hide(); }

        if(currentTime == costCons && costChosen == true){  video1[0].pause(); }

        if(currentTime == choiceHeart && choiceHeartchosen == false){  video1[0].pause(); }          


        if(currentTime == qualityQuestion && qualityChosen == false){  video1[0].pause(); }


        if(currentTime == qualityQuestion && costChosen == false){

            video1[0].pause();

        }

        if(currentTime == qualityQuestion && costChosen == true){

            video1[0].play();

        }

        if (currentTime == qualityQuestion && qualityChosen == true) {
            video1[0].playPauseVideo();        }


        if(currentTime == badChoicePart && goodChoiceChosen == true){
            video1[0].pause();
        }

        if(currentTime == videoHalfWay){
            // Halfway point
        }

        if(currentTime == durationNum){
            // Video complete
        }

    });

});

function onTrackedVideoFram(curretTime, duration){
    $('.current').text(curretTime);
    $('.duration').text(duration);
}

function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
    return ((h > 0 ? h + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + m + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s);
}

function playPauseVideo(popUp){
    if(video1[0].paused){
        video1[0].play();
    } else{
        video1[0].pause();
        $.featherlight($(popUp));
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

The video does not play after 30 sec despite which ever choice boxes are clicked.

Html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive Video</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Skeleton CSS & Featherlight -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/featherlight.css">
    <script src="js/featherlight.js"></script>

    <!-- Interaction CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/interaction.css">

    <!-- Interaction js -->
    <script src="js/interaction.js"></script>

    <!-- GreenSock -->
    <script src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">


            <div class="row videoArea">


            <div class="box1" style="z-index: 2"></div>


            <div class="box2" style="z-index: 2"></div>

            <div class="box3" style="z-index: 2"></div>
            <div class="box4" style="z-index: 2"></div>

            <div class="videoCont">

                <video id="video1" controls autoplay="true">
                <source src="media/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
             </div>         

        </div>

        <div class="row descArea">

            <h5>Video Title</h5>
            <p>This is the description</p>
            <div class="current">0:00</div>
            <div class="duration">0:00</div>

        </div>

    </div> <!-- End of Container -->

    <div class="lightbox popUpQuestion1">
        <h4>Question 1</h4>
        <p>Think about what you learned and then how would you respond?</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="button longBtns goodChoice">Calmly respond with helpful info</a>
        <a href="#" class="button longBtns badChoice">Why is he asking me this question?</a>
    </div>

    <div class="lightbox persona1PopUp">
        <img src="images/Justin.jpg">
        <h5>Justins Hanks</h5>
        <p>Role: Development Manager</p>
        <p>Bio: Justin has been a manager for 4 years. sakjdhsakjdh askjdh ksajhd aksjh askjdhksajd askjhd askjhdkjsah </p>
        <p>Previous Experiences</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Experience 1: 2002-2004</li>
            <li>Experience 2: 2005-2009</li>
            <li>Experience 3: 2010-2016</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="lightbox persona2PopUp">
        <img src="images/Matt.jpg">
        <h5>Matt Briscoe</h5>
        <p>Role: Developer</p>
        <p>Bio: Matt has been a manager for 4 years. This alkjdlas asldkjasldj aslkdj aklsdjlsakdjalskjd salkdj salkjd</p>
        <p>Previous Experiences</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Experience 1: 2002-2004</li>
            <li>Experience 2: 2005-2009</li>
            <li>Experience 3: 2010-2016</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Css :

```
body{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p{
    margin: 0;
}

video{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.container{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.descArea{
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #c8c8c8;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.videoArea{
    position: relative;
}

.box1{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 198, 10, 1);
    width: 10%;
    height: 15%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 44%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:opacity 500ms;
}

.box2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(125, 185, 42, 1);
    width: 10%;
    height: 15%;
    top: 32%;
    left: 26%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:opacity 500ms;
}

.box3{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(160, 185, 42, 1);
    width: 31%;
    height: 46%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 7%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:opacity 500ms;
}

.box4{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(125, 285, 42, 1);
    width: 33%;
    height: 47%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 59%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:opacity 500ms;
}


.lightbox{
    display: none;
}

.longBtns{
    display: block;
}

.videoCont{
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Please, help me to figure this out.

Comment: putting this in a working jsfiddle would help

Comment: Can you help ?? like through skype ?? It would be much appreciated..

Comment: Also the video I used is in my media folder in my computer, doing it through fiddle would mean I'd have to link it through url and upload somewhere, additional steps like those at this point would only confuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a major lack of example code, I'm going to take a stab and say that if you were to look at your web console an error will be displayed about the following function not existing on the object:

```
if(currentTime == qualityQuestion && qualityChosen == true)
{
  video1[0].playPauseVideo();
}
```

It should probably read:

```
if(currentTime == qualityQuestion && qualityChosen == true)
{
  playPauseVideo();
}
```

Comment: var video1;

$(document).ready(function(){

    video1 = $('#video1');

This already defines what video1 is .. doesnt it?

Comment: playPauseVideo as a function does not exist on the object video1[0], though. Check your developer console and look for javascript errors.